# Place a text above two different solid background colors

Tags: html, css, background-color

Does anyone know how to place a text over two different solid background colors? At the same time it remains responsive when minimizing the screen. I have seen this being done alot, however, I am still researching the standard  method to coding this style. Below I added the image of the style I wanted to do. Thank you for your time.

[image: image displaying text over two solid colors]

Comment: Draw two rectangles on top of each other with two different colors, then position the text over the rectangles

Comment: What have you tried? Please post code you've tried before just asking how to do stuff in StackOverflow.

Comment: This is really easy to do with CSS gradients. https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: Draw a box. 60x40, draw 2 boxes inside the box. 60x20 & 60x20 each with the color you want.

Position text in middle of 60x40 box.
Done.

Comment: What do I draw the boxes with? a pencil or in photoshop? and if a pencil what type should I use?

Comment: @ricky As in use elements in HTML... such as a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think CSS gradients is the way to go. You can set where the color stop is positioned if you need to. It also doesn't rely on setting a height.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee615f, #ee615f 50%, #9f3e3e 50%, #9f3e3e);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#div2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee615f, #ee615f 25%, #9f3e3e 25%, #9f3e3e);
}

#div3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee615f, #ee615f 75%, #9f3e3e 75%, #9f3e3e);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">COLOR STOP AT 50%</div>

<div id="div2">COLOR STOP AT 25%</div>

<div id="div3">COLOR STOP AT 75%</div>
```

Here's more info on using them: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. https://jsfiddle.net/67uxvnq7/1/

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:50vh;
  background: pink;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span>HELLO WORLD</span>
</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
```